# Android App crashes when element's id is set, Xamarin Android

Tags: xml, xamarin.android

I'm developing simple app with Xamarin Android. I have an Recycler View and I want to add TextView below all elements. It works almost well. When the axml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/regularExpensesRecyclerView" />
<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but if i set an id for my TextView

```
    <TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"/>
```

I get an InvocationTargetException. I have no idea what can cause such behaviour.

Comment: Hello, your code is correct, can you show the complete error logs? Or try to delete the obj and bin folder and restart your VS to rebuild your project.

Comment: cleaning and rebuilding worked, thanks for effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simplier than I thought. Cleaning the solution before almost every deploy prevents errors with Id's